# EF 7 Code First Entity with Object Property having Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a project that I am playing with using Code First, and I have a few objects that utilize a ProcurmentData class which has a relationship to a Supplier:

```
public class ProcurmentData { 
    public virtual Supplier? Supplier { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }
}
```

I have multiple classes that use ProcurmentData where I would like to have the ProcurmentData embedded into the table, but EF doesn't like ProcurmentData doesnt have a Key:

> EntityType 'ProcurmentData' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

If I remove Supplier, it works, and I can see Procurment_PurchaseDate in the table for example. I can't inherit ProcurmentData because C# doesn't support multiple object inheritance and need to use the inheritance to derive Discriminator on the classes in some cases such as:

```
public class Tool
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
public class HomemadeTool : Tool
{
    public int BuildHours { get; set; }
}
public class PowerTool : Tool
{
    public int Voltage { get; set; }
    public ProcurmentData? Procurment { get; set; }
}

public class Block {
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public ProcurmentData? Procurment {get;set;}
}
```

Is there a way to keep the data stored as part of the record directly, I'd prefer not to use a relationship from these items to a ProducurmentDatas table, and would like to keep ProcurmentData as its own type if I ever want to extend it.

If I remove the reference from ProcurmentData to Supplier, I can get it to generate, but I am tracking suppliers so need that relationship.

Comment: Read about Owned Entities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - this was what it needed apparently!